# single sign on with on premise AD

Tags: php, azure, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

I have to integrate single sign on with on premise AD (ADFS method).My application in registered in onpremise windows ADFS server and have client ID and secrete.For testing I have registered my app in azure and have client ID and secrete.

I have tried with open id connect.While using the azure registered client ID and secrete. I'm able to login but I tried with onpremise ID and secrete in php .
  I caught

> AADSTS700016: Application with identifier
>   '450bbcf3-a17a-456515-452-4552' was not found in the directory
>   '45112b2-e087-4d29-9642-817873fddc4c'. This can happen if the
>   application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant
>   or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your
>   authentication request to the wrong tenant

45112b2-e087-4d29-9642-817873fddc4c is a azure created folder(tenent)

How to integrate AD FS with onpremise registered ID and secrete.

Comment: If you want to login against Azure AD, you need to use the app registered in Azure AD. Same for ADFS. You need to login against ADFS directly to use the ADFS registered app.

Comment: I dont want to use AZURE AD .I want to use on premise AD

Comment: Does ADFS 2.0 even support OAuth/OIDC? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-concepts that only applies to Server 2016 or later (ADFS 4.0+). You tagged your question with adfs2.0 though...

Answer (score 0):

You have to authenticate directly against ADFS as per these [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-openid-connect-with-ad-fs).

There are other samples in that documentation as well.

You cannot do this with ADFS 2.0. Ideally, you need ADFS 4.0 or 5.0 (server 2016 / 2019).